# JMS message content as XML

Tags: ballerina

Regarding to the answers [in this issue](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/5695) it seems that it isn't possible to convert a string to XML in Ballerina other than in "relevant places" (http payload mentioned).

We are in need of reading message content as XML in a JMS subscription, but I get stuck with a string (after calling the getTextMessageContent()). Isn't JMS content considered a "relevant place" or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Can you share the code you are trying? Also the xml content you are trying to convert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for how to directly convert a string to xml, then you could use the `readXml` function in `StringReader` object.

Following example shows how you could use the `StringReader`.

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    string str = "<foo>hello</foo>";
    io:StringReader sr = new(str, encoding = "UTF-8");
    xml? x = check sr.readXml();
    io:println(x);
}
```

More info about StringReader API's can be found from here - https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/io.html#StringReader